# GridBagLayout does not fill area

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a component that is inserted into the main content pane, and for some reason, it is not filling the area.

```
getInstance().add(internalPanel, LayoutFactory.newFactory().setX(1).setY(1).
            setWeightX(1).setWeightY(1).setFill(GridBagConstraints.BOTH));
```

I made the `LayoutFactory` specifically for `GridBagLayout`, it just sets the property and returns the object.

Basically, the problem is that when I add the component to the content pane, it does not fill the space dedicated for it. It takes the absolute minimum, as if `weightX` and `weightY` were set to 0. I have tried to `setAnchor(GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START)` and `setAnchor(GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST)`. Neither have any visible effect on the program.

Also, when I set the border of the component, it only fills part of the space, so it is not a problem with the component I am adding to it.

It is worth noting that the component shows up in the centre of the space, and does not follow the anchor. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275189/why-does-gridbaglayout-center-my-components-instead-of-putting-it-in-the-corner), I figured my problem was the `weightX`and`weightY` properties. Looking at the other components of the content pane, the weight is set on every one of them.

```
getInstance().add(MainFrame.buttons, LayoutFactory.newFactory().setX(0).setY(1).
            setWeightY(1).setWeightX(0).setFill(GridBagConstraints.BOTH));
```

and

```
getInstance().add(panel, LayoutFactory.newFactory().setX(0).setY(0).setWidth(2)
            .setWeightX(1).setWeightY(0).setAnchor(GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START)
            .setFill(GridBagConstraints.NONE));
```

It's certainly possible that something is going wrong somewhere else, but I didn't want to swamp this post with text. If you need more information to figure this out, I'd be more than glad to provide it. Hopefully this made sense. I've been using `GridBagLayout` for a while now and I've never run into something like this.

[Here is an image of what it looks like in the space it is supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ibEX.png)

EDIT: Found out the problem lays somewhere else, as making a small example program works fine. Since I am a little stumped, [I uploaded a full version of the program I am working on.](http://www.mediafire.com/?b75inpohfwhl9sd) Don't worry about what it actually does, I just care about the workload panel not filling the space.

Comment: Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) so that we can run and manipulate your code. Also am I understanding you correctly that you're setting weights to 0?

Comment: Yes. Well, I guess the problem lays somewhere else, because when I made an sscce, it worked perfectly. [Available here.](http://pastebin.com/piAtgqmc)

Comment: I think that you need to do more debugging to at least isolate the error so that if you can't fix it, you'll be able to post your sscce.

Comment: That's what I will do. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to problem :

Was adding component to `InternalPanel` type object, which had no layout manager. (Defaulted to flowLayout)

Comment: Why is this an issue? Please explain fully how this helped/solved the problem.